# The intersection of a closure with an open set

Tags: general-topology

I have been stuck on this problem :

Prove :If $A$ is Open , then $A\cap \overline B \subset \overline {A \cap B}$.I have tried to use the previously proven fact that $\overline {A \cap B}\subset \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$ , but I cannot seem to get anywhere ...In particular, I do not see how A being open is relevant here..........

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to refresh your memory (I guess?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x \in A \cap \overline{B}$. So $x \in A$ and $x \in \overline{B}$.

Let $O$ be any open set that contains $x$. Then, as $A$ is open, $O \cap A$ is an open set that contains $x$ as well. Because $x \in \overline{B}$, $(O \cap A) \cap B \neq \emptyset$. But this also says that $O \cap (A \cap B) \neq \emptyset$.

As $O$ was arbitary open with $x \in O$, this shows that $x \in \overline{A \cap B}$, thereby showing the inclusion.

Comment: Thanks , much obliged

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a definition for closure which I think is suitable for this task (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)): Let $B\subset X$
$$\overline{B}=\{x\in X:\ \exists (x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset B\mbox{ such that }x_n\rightarrow x\}.$$
Now let $x\in A\cap\overline{B}$ be arbitrary. Since $A$ is open there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_\varepsilon(x)\subset A$ and there also exists a sequence $x_n\in B$ with $x_n\rightarrow x$. Hence there exists an $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n\geq n_0$ we have $x_n\in B_{\varepsilon}(x)$. Hence $x_n\in A\cap B$ and $x_n\rightarrow x$. Therefore $x\in \overline{A\cap B}$.

Comment: We are working in topological spaces. You cannot take real numbers like $\varepsilon$ in every topological spaces!

Comment: @ GhD Then take an open neighbourhood instead of $B_\varepsilon(x)$, and the proof will work anyway.

Comment: Then you should write a new proof. Now your proof uses methods which are true just in metric spaces.

Comment: Nah, I leave it as an exercise to replace every $B_\varepsilon(x)$ with an open $U$ containing $x$.

Comment: And replace sequences by nets as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a \in A\cap \overline B$.

Since $A$ is open, for every open set $V$ containing $a$ there is an open set $U:=V\cap A$ containing $a$.

$a \in \overline B$ so $V\cap(A\cap B)=U\cap B\ne\varnothing$. Now we have $a \in \overline {A \cap B}$.