# On necessary and sufficient condition for a set to be open

Tags: general-topology

Let $G \subset X$ then $G$ is open if and only if for all $A \subset X$, $\overline{G \cap A} = \overline{G \cap \overline{A}}$.\
I can prove one inclusion but not the other... Not sure how to use the fact that G is open also... Any tips?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): include the work you have already done, and your attempts to prove the rest. While doing so, don't forget it is an "iff".

Comment: For the inclusion you cannot prove (assuming $G$ is open), there was a duplicate: [The intersection of a closure with an open set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2502937). As for the converse implication, see this more recent post: [Why does this condition about closures characterize open sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4292293).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let cl K be $\overline K.$

Prove the important lemma if U is open, 
then U $\cap$ cl A $\subseteq$ cl (U $\cap$ A).

Thus for open G, cl (G $\cap$ A) $\subseteq$ cl (G $\cap$ cl A)
$\subseteq$ cl cl (G $\cap$ A) = cl (G $\cap$ A) and equality follows.

For the converse, set A = X - G in the equation.

Comment: [Proof of the "lemma"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2503000/386889) and [of the converse](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4292385/386889) but anyway, we should not answer such a "no-effort question".