# Why does this condition about closures characterize open sets?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ a topologic space and $U\subseteq X$, then $U\in \tau \iff$ for all $A⊆X,$ $\overline{U\cap\bar{A}}=\overline{U\cap A}.$

I already proved that [if $U$ is an open subset of $X$, then the equality holds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678310) using that $x\in\bar{A} \iff$ every open set $U$ containing $x$ intersects $A$.

But im stucked trying to prove that in fact, $U$ is an open set if I assume equality. My first try was to use the same theorem but I didn't get anything and then I tried to prove that  $U$=int$U$ but is that the way to prove it or I'm missing something?

EXTRA: I know that $\overline{U\cap\bar{A}}=\overline{U\cap A}$ tells me that $U$ is very close to $\bar{A}$ as well as $A$, so in fact, $U$ must be open :c
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Proving that $U = \mathrm{int}(U)$ would be an approach you could use, yes, since a set is open iff it equals its interior. Whether that proof would be easy, I don't know. You should also clarify what the set $A$ in question is. Is it a particular set? Must this hold for all sets $A$?

Comment: Oh, yes I forgot to mention it, $A\subseteq X$

Comment: The quantifiers in your statement seem wrong. As written it's false: when $A = \varnothing$, we get $\overline{U \cap \overline{A}} = \overline{U \cap A} = \varnothing$ whether or not $U$ is open. Do you maybe mean "Let $U \subseteq X$. Then $U \in \tau$ if and only if for all $A \subseteq X$,  $\overline{U \cap \overline{A}} = \overline{U \cap A}$"? That stands some chance of being true, though I haven't looked at it carefully.

Comment: I see, you are right, let me edit it, thanks @MishaLavrov.

Comment: I don’t understand the title.

Comment: Hint: take $A = X \setminus U$ and prove $A$ is closed.

Comment: I've edited the title to be more descriptive of what's going on. @Crimmi, feel free to change it if you really don't like it, but I think it will help other people with similar questions.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkSaving! Was a very useful hint :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw Misha Lavrov solution, and thanks for the ones who answered and helped me to fix the problem of quantiers with the subset $A$. Now I gonna show my solution:
I'm gonna prove that $X\backslash U$ is a closed set of X, i.e $\overline{X\backslash U}\subseteq X\backslash U$\
Since for all $A \subseteq X$, $\overline{U\cap\bar{A}}=\overline{U\cap A}$, consider $A=X\backslash U$ hence, $U\cap\overline{X\backslash U}\subseteq \overline{U\cap\overline{X\backslash U}}=\overline{U\cap X\backslash U} $ but U\cap $U\cap X\backslash U=\emptyset$ and $\bar{\emptyset}=\emptyset$. Therefore, $U\cap\overline{X\backslash U}=\emptyset$.

So $\overline{X\backslash U}\subseteq X\backslash U $ so, $\overline{X\backslash U}=X\backslash U$, that means, $X\backslash U$ is a closed subset of X, indeed $U$ is open in X.

Answer (score 1):

To use the property "for all $A \subseteq X$, $\overline{U\cap\bar{A}}=\overline{U\cap A}$", it makes sense to pick some cleverly chosen $A$, depending on $U$, and apply the property to that $A$.

I admit that my first attempts were to try $A = \varnothing$, $A = X$, and $A = U$, and neither of those tell us anything useful about $U$.

But if we try setting $A = U^c$ (that is, the complement $X-U$), then the resulting condition $\overline{U\cap\overline {U^c}}=\overline{U\cap U^c}$ simplifies nicely:

- First, to $\overline{U\cap\overline{U^c}} = \overline{\varnothing} = \varnothing$. (Having the RHS simplify in this way was my motivation to try $A = U^c$ to begin with.)
- If $\overline S = \varnothing$, then $S = \varnothing$. (Why?) Therefore $U \cap \overline{U^c} = \varnothing$.
- We have $\overline{U^c} = (\operatorname{int}(U))^c$. (Why?) Therefore $U \cap (\operatorname{int}(U))^c = \varnothing$, which is another way of saying $U \subseteq \operatorname{int}(U)$. This is only true if $U$ is open.

Comment: Sorry for answering too late @Misha. Finally my professor helped my with the solution and in I already wrote my solution. I hope it helps you too and thanks :D

Comment: You could have stick to the closure operator... $\emptyset = \overline{\emptyset} = \overline{U \cap U^c} \supset U \cap \overline{U^c}$ means that $\overline{U^c} \subset U^c$. And this means that $U^c$ is closed.

Comment: @AndréCaldas Yes, there are many ways to finish the proof.